# How to Insert svg images in PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint

I was able to add svg images into PPT so far, now suddenly unable to add them. when I add, it comes as internet explore icon with name of the image. anybody have any ideas why it changed suddenly? Is there any way without opening it in Illustrator and bring to ppt?

Comment: SVG is a new feature in some versions of PPT and hasn't shown up in all of them. Are you using Mac or Windows? What version/build of Office and is it a subscription version or not?  And how exactly are you adding the SVG images?

Comment: this is off-topic as it's not a coding question.

Comment: I'm using a Office 2016 on a Windows PC, licensed but not subscription version. Tried adding from insert picture and also drag and drop to slide, both were working so far and suddenly stopped working and I don't know how to get it working

Comment: MS seems to make mistakes in their update processes from time to time. I've seen other reports of new features appearing in non-subscription versions, then disappearing again, and on subscription versions I've seen features that were there suddenly disappear then later re-appear.  Unless you have one of the enterprise editions that gets certain feature updates when the IT department authorizes it, I'd assume that you've witnessed that MS "now you see it, now you don't" trick.

Comment: haha.. apparently, i made the latest Office update hoping to get a better version, least i knew its the Pandora box, my most useful feature is gone. is there any workaround? I tried the registry fix to set the allow list Dword, thats not helping either..

Comment: If the feature is truly not meant for your particular version of Office, I don't know of any trick that'll make it available other than waiting until the next major update, which should make the newer features available in all editions. Unfortunately, that's probably going to be called Office 2019, which gives some hint as to how long you'll need to hold your breath (don't). And it may be a paid update. You might be better off looking for a vector drawing program that can import SVG and export something PPT will import (or that can copy/paste to PPT in acceptable form).  InkScape seems popular

Comment: Thanks Steve, That's sensible. Only thing that made me ask for it is taking away the features I had in the name of an update

Comment: After few weeks, I found MS Word 2016 still had the Insert icons feature, so it did support pasting svg images. I was happily using Word instead of illustrator as a bridge to take the svg icons to PPT. The very cunning Microsoft has taken that feature from Word as well, since I started using it :) leaving me in disdain and shock!

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following workaround: import the SVG file into a LibreOffice Impress (it might look a bit ugly in LibreOffice, but don't worry), and then save this as a PowerPoint presentation.

When you open this file in PowerPoint, you'll find that your vector graphic will be correctly displayed.

Note that the feature to import vector graphics is included in Microsoft's subscription-based Office 365.

Comment: Thanks, will try it! some of these issues gets fixed when opened with Google Slides first and save as PPT, then open in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2):

In the web version of PowerPoint you can drag and drop an SVG from your computer into a slide and it will be inserted as an image.